# Polynomial linear diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x)X_i(x)=0$ be a polynomial linear equation (the $a_i(x)$ are in $\mathbb C[x]$). Assume that one knows a particular solution $(X_{0,1},\cdots,X_{0,n})$ of this equation. Does there exist an algorithm or a formula giving all the solutions of this equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What equation? I don't see an equals sign (not counting the $i=1$ index of summation).

Comment: Oops!! I edited the post! Thanks for the remark

Comment: The $X_i$ are also supposed to be polynomials with complex coefficients? Anyway, if we were dealing with numbers, I don't think that knowing the one solution $(3,2,0,0,0)$ of $2a-3b+97c+101d+103e=0$ would be of much use in finding all the integer solutions; I can't see the story with polynomials being any different.